# How to fix messed up Copying of CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to copy a bunch of csv files into 1 big csv.
all 3 files have the same column headers, but I changed them to be according to the files name. For example, file arousal_a_103_happy.csv  will now be in the new csv in the column header for it's columns.

My issue, is that
1st: it copies the file in a very strange order, it does not flip it, it's just every column is wherever it wants to be.
2nd: it doesnt copy the files next to eachother, but more like a slope. so if the first file finishes at P23, the new file will start at Q24.

This is the code:

```
def concatenate(path = "C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\Work\\subject", outfile = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Work\\subject\\concatenated.csv"):
    os.chdir(path)
    fileList=glob.glob("*happy.csv")
    dfList=[]
    print(fileList)
    i=1
    string = "subject" 
    for files in fileList:
        df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work\\subject\\" + files, encoding ='CP1255') #Get's error because of the link!
        sub = files
        i+=1
        ColNames =[sub + " Level",  sub +" Description", sub+" Number",sub+" Onset_Date",sub+" Onset_Time",sub+" Offset_Date",sub+" Offset_Time",sub+" Duration_Date",sub+" Duration_Time",sub+" Arousal",sub+" Gaze",sub+" Movement"   , sub+" Vocalization", sub+" eyes covered", sub+" Mother\'s arrousal", sub+"    Transcript"]
        df.columns=ColNames
        dfList.append(df)

    concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index=True, verify_integrity=True)
    concatDf.to_csv(outfile, index=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Fetching files
import csv
FileNames = []
path="C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\Work\\subject\\"
os.chdir(path)
for counter, files in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    FileNames.append(files)
print (FileNames)



# Merging all .csv from your folder 'subject'
pathout="C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\\Work\\subject\\"
for filenames in SortedFileNames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames,encoding='utf-8')
    saved_column = df.tweet
    saved_column.to_csv(pathout+"mixed.csv", mode='a')
print("File Created Sucessfully mixed.csv")
```